# Git branches in one line

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Im recently started learning git and had a test that contains next task: 
To create project and basic function in master branch, than to create second branch and every next function to commit in that branch and merge with master. So after commit in master branch i create second, checkout to it and add. , commit  and merge to master. And got something similar to the picture on left, but result should look like picture on right. what did I do wrong? [branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIUB5.png)

Comment: Left picture looks like this [link]https://ibb.co/eD4CdJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So after commit in master branch i create second, checkout to it and add. , commit and merge to master

Step by step:

1. `C1 <- C2`  master is now on C2
2. Checkout to branch `br`: master is on C2 and br is on C2.
3. Commit to `br`: `C1 <- C2(master) <- C3 (br)`
4. Merge `br` into `master` is done by fast-forward. `C1 <- C2 <- C3 (master)(br)`

Try `git merge --no-ff`